# Win32 MFC OnPaint Resizing and Redrawing handling

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, win32gui

how to handle this problem everytime i resize my drawing seems to not draw right.
i think i need to call Invalidate() everytime i resize the window but doesnt WM_PAINT automatically called every time i move or resize the window?

```
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(rect);
if (IsIconic())
{
    //CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

    // Center icon in client rectangle
    int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
    int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

    // Draw the icon
    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
}
else
{

    for(int ndx(0); ndx < rect.Width() - 150; ndx += 10)
    {
        dc.MoveTo( rect.left + 50, rect.bottom / 2 );

        dc.LineTo( rect.left + 50 + ndx, rect.bottom / 2 );

    }
    CBrush mybrush(RGB(30,30,30));
    dc.FillRect( CRect(rect.left + 10, rect.top + 10, rect.Width() / 4, rect.Height() / 4),&mybrush );
    CDialogEx::OnPaint();
}
```

Before Resizing:[image]

After Resizing:[image]

Comment: `WM_PAINT` messages are generated on resize, as long as the window class is registered with the `CS_HREDRAW` and/or `CS_VREDRAW` class styles. The system automatically erases the background using the brush specified in the window class. Window class here refers to [WNDCLASS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx), not `CWnd`. Use Spy++ to examine the window class styles on your window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this is the optimal solution.

1. In your paint code, before painting, fill the entire client area with the background color:

   ```
     dc.FillSolidRect(&rect, ...);
   ```

   Remove `CDialogEx::OnPaint()`.
2. Add an [`OnEraseBkgnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0a52fkz.aspx) handler:

   ```
     BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication1Dlg, CDialogEx)
       //...
       ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
     END_MESSAGE_MAP()

     //...

     BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC * pDC)
     {
       RedrawWindow();
       return TRUE;
     }
   ```
3. If the dialog is flickering, use MFC's CMemDC (undocumented).

Comment: yup yup yup. this fixes it. this require handling of WM_ERASEBKGND. thanks alot sir.

Answer (score 1):

When you start painting and use `CPaintDC` it doesn't make sense to call the base class that tries this again and may again erase the background...

What happens.

1. Your `CPaintDC` ist created
2. `BeginPaint` is called and `WM_ERASEBKGND` is sent.
3. You paint your stuff.
4. You call the base class anbd a new `CPaintDC` calles `BeginPaint`.
5. Because `EndPaint` isn't called the paint area isn't validated. So `BeginPaint` is executed and the `WM_ERASEBKGND` is called again.
6. Finally the `CPaintDC`'s destructors are called and the client area is validated.

Never call the OnPaint baseclass function if you start using `CPaintDC`/`BeginPaint`!

Comment: you meant this  CDialogEx::OnPaint(); right? ive tried removing it out but still having same result.

Comment: Although it seems more plausible, that `EndPaint` were to clear the dirty area, it really is `BeginPaint` that validates the invalid region.

Answer (score -1):

this is fixes my problem

step 1: BeginPaint()

```
// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CTestDrawDlg::OnPaint()
{
CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(rect);

// draw background manually
EraseBkgnd(&dc);

if (IsIconic())
{
    //CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

    // Center icon in client rectangle
    int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
    int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
    int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

    // Draw the icon
    dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
}
else
{

    for(int ndx(0); ndx < rect.Width() - 150; ndx += 10)
    {
        dc.MoveTo( rect.left + 50, rect.bottom / 2 );

        dc.LineTo( rect.left + 50 + ndx, rect.bottom / 2 );

    }
    CBrush mybrush(RGB(30,30,30));
    dc.FillRect( CRect(rect.left + 10, rect.top + 10, rect.Width() / 4, rect.Height() / 4),&mybrush );
}
}
```

STEP: 2 RedrawWindow() on WM_ERASEBACKGND

```
BOOL CTestDrawDlg::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

RedrawWindow();
return TRUE;
}
```

and Manually draw the background

```
void CTestDrawDlg::EraseBkgnd( CDC * pDC )
{
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(rect);
pDC->FillSolidRect(rect, RGB(255,255,255));

// paint whatever you want in the background

}
```

STEP 3: EndPaint()

Comment: Calling Redraw Window in OnEraseBkGnd ist definitively wrong!

Comment: yup its memory expansive.. can you provide a better way of doing it?